# How to set a range with visible cells only in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that sets up an email with a selected Range as the body of the email. However, despite the range selected having hidden rows, the range copied has all the rows. Is there a way to copy only the visible? I have tried using SpecialCells(xltypeVisibleOnly) but to no success. Any suggestions?

```
Sub Button6_Click()

Dim dt As Date
Dim rBody(0) As Range
Dim b As Boolean

dt = [RefDate]

With shtDash
    Set rBody(0) = .Range("Print_Mail")
End With

b = SendMail(rBody, "subject" & dt, [to_mail], [cc_mail])

If Not b Then
    MsgBox "Error running mail macro. Please debug."
End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: I have tried setting .Range("Print_Mail").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) but it doesn't work. b returns false. clarifying, rBody must be a range due to the way the SendMail function is coded.

Comment: Look up `SpecialCells`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells)

Comment: as said in op, doesn't work.

Comment: Copy the visible cells to a blank sheet and then send the pasted range